# Getting a sub-function to modify variables

Tags: c, pointers

This is a simple test program where I am trying to get the func function to modify the variables a and b which are then used in the main function. Is there a way to get func to return the modified variables so they can be used? (preferably without using struct as I don't understand how it works)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int a, int b)
{
    a=a+1;
    b=b+1;
}

void main(void)
{
    int a=0, b=0;
    while (1)
    {
        func(a,b);
        printf("%d\n",a);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need [pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify variables in the calling function, you have to pass their address to `func` (i.e. pass a pointer to these variables

```
void func(int* a, int* b)
{
    *a=*a+1;
    *b=*b+1;
}

func(&a,&b);
```

Your code passes its arguments by value.  This means that `a` and `b` are copied into new variables which are initialised with the values of the calling variables but only exist for the duration of `func`.

Comment: +1 Please expand the answer to explain that OP's code has local copies of the variables

Answer (score 0):

I agree. The best way to do this is using [pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html). But are you aware that your code will never terminate? You should use a condition that can end excution of the while loop.

Also, if you wanna perfom the exact same action to both variables you could just use the return statement like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(int a, int b)
{
    return a+1;
}

void main(void)
{
    int a=0, b=0;

    while (a < 5)
    {
        func(a);
        func(b);
        printf("%d\n",a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve through pointers . Don't use While(1) because it will go to infinite loop. I think following program help to you.

```
  #include <stdio.h>

    void func(int* a, int* b)
    {
    *a=*a+1;
    *b=*b+1;
    }

    void main(void)
    {
    int a=0, b=0;
    //while (1)
    //    {
        func(&a,&b);
        printf("%d\n",a);
      //  }
    }
```